# selenium webdriver : click transaction id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have  transaction table,

There is a id listed in the first column,  I want to click it to open the record to edit it.

How do i do that?
I am able to navigate to transaction table but this element fails `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='"+searchid+"']")));`

Can some help debug/ advise me?Thanks so much

[image]

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\rahul\\Downloads\\chromedriver\\84\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com/login");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_email']"))).sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_password']")).sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Log In')]")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Operations')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'View')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()=('Transaction(s)')]"))).click();      
    
    
    WebElement searchidbox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input']")));
    
    searchidbox.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    searchidbox.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    searchidbox.sendKeys(searchid);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root' and @title='Search']")).click();
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']"));
    search.click();
    
    WebElement searchreacord = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='"+searchid+"']")));
    searchreacord.click();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your error ? What kind of issue are you facing ? you can pass string with your xpath

Comment: on my screen..i can't find the document number and click.the one in red crircle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com/login");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_email']"))).sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_password']")).sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Log In')]")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Operations')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'View')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()=('Transaction(s)')]"))).click();


    WebElement searchidbox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input']")));
    String searchid ="CIE-00026";
    searchidbox.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    searchidbox.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    searchidbox.sendKeys(searchid);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root' and @title='Search']")).click();
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']"));
    search.click();

    WebElement searchreacord = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='"+searchid+"']")));
    searchreacord.click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that by either of the following  method. I have tried and it works.

```
element.click()   # Positions the cursor at the end of the string
element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE )
```

element is your id of that field

Comment: then element, the  text circled in red has NO id.  so how am i to get the elemnt by id

Comment: Hello @RahulSK Please provide URL or DOM for better understanding.

Comment: Please share URL here so that i can tell about elements pick

Comment: @ Pythonologist /testingapp.workspez.com/login then click operations - > view ->transactions

Comment: Username and password to login